VS Code is no longer running my code correctly and won't display anything new in the terminal window
I've been working on a C++ course for a while now and I was trying to complete a section challenge when something broke. I've tested this with many other files that have worked before, but all of them have this same exact problem, so I know this has nothing to do with the code I wrote.
I tried getting help in another post initially, but nothing could resolve it. I'm writing this as an update on things I've found in hopes that it might point to what's wrong.
I'm using Visual Studio Code. I like using this since it means I can run my files individually and not have to keep opening up new projects considering most of what I've written is notes that I'd like to refer back to. Someone recommended checking out this post, but the directory someone in the debugging recommended you delete files from doesn't seem to exist for me. Specifically, this directory: %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.6.0-insiders
Here's what I've found that's different. I've been pushing all of my changes to a repo on GitHub, and I noticed it's been trying to tell me to push changes to files I've never seen before. Here's a list of the files there have apparently been changes in.

ProjectSettings.json
slnx.sqlite
VSWorkspaceState.json
Browse.VC.db
DocumentLayout.json
.wsuo
three seperate files with a mix of numbers, letters, and dashes ending in ".vsidx"

At the recommendation of another user, I also tried running the code from a seperate Command Line window and the code ran just fine, displaying exactly what I expected.
When I try running my code in VS Code, this is the only thing that displays in the terminal area:
PS C:\Users\ME\Workspaces\Udemy-CPP-Course-1>  & 'c:\Users\screa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.20.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-rcuibzlp.gg0' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-xahdcvga.jh4' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-rkxr5wlu.jlp' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-jnam5jyw.xuc' '--dbgExe=C:\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' 
If push comes to shove, I'm willing to delete and reinstall VS Code, but I'd rather avoid that so I don't need to reinstall all the extensions I have in place nor get the settings the way I like them.
Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do next?

There is a chance that the answers (read all of them) to How to reinstall VSCode without losing extensions and user settings still work. Of course, you have a rigorous backup scheme in operation so that you can retrieve any data, don't you? ;)

@AndrewMorton I will definitely check it out if nothing else can fix my problem. Thank you. And if by backup scheme you mean me lamenting the loss of my beautiful settings, then yes. Very rigorous. hahaha

Please edit your original question rather than opening a new one
